# Method for Storing and organizing data submitted by user to a website (form, pdf)?

Tags: php, sql, database, web

I have completed a website for a startup consultancy office and am confused on database part. User is supposed to upload basic information using form and resume in pdf format. How should I organize data so that it get stored, say, in Excel sheet or anything like that. Office people are not supposed to have data administration knowledge. They should get data whenever user upload a form. Any standard/preferred way? How can I implement it?

Comment: I think you have to give more details. Have you already decided which techniques to use ? Is there something like a MySQL database that you could use ? Or would you need to store the received data on the webserver ? Would sending an email with the attached to a certain email address be enough ?

Comment: Yes, I have MySQL running on my server. And PHP will be used as a script to store data in database tables. But next what? They are not supposed to login in to database. Some way to automatically data being transferred someplace where its access is as easy opening an excel sheet.

Comment: And I dont want it to simply get emailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of options:

- you might switch from Excel to Access (if your customer has a license for it) and have Access read the same database your PHP program writes to. To notify them of changes you can send an email (only for notification, not for transfer of the document itself
- you can create a second web application for them which they use to access the data stored. This application can poll the database for changes or can be notified when something was written by the first application (you can use techniques like websockets)

I would go for option two: create that application and create an icon on their Windows desktop that leads them to the website. If this is easier to implement you can combine this with option 1: send an email whenever a new document was uploaded, that email contains a link to your second application

Comment: Am going for Access :)

Comment: @mustafamukadam congratulations, so you have a solution (or at least decision ;-)) to your problem. You should accept an answer to show the others that you don't need assistance any longer.

Answer (score 1):

With the data already in a MySQL-database it is propably easiest to make a web-frontend for the database.
Her you can - behind a login - show newly entered data (and all entered data if you choose) - in the way you want.